# Android XML to JSON Bug org.json Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.XMLTokener.end

Tags: android, json, xml, org.json

I am suffering this error in `Android development` when converting `XML to JSON` which includes `CDATA tag`. It works fine in normal `Java`.

I have used `Library`.

`org.json`.

```
 public Document fetchXMLHTTP(String httpUrl) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setCoalescing(true); // This removes CDATA Tag and converts it ", this doesn't work in Android 



        Log.v("xml_parser", "Coalescing Aware: " + factory.isCoalescing());
        if(factory.isNamespaceAware()){
        }
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        URL uri = new URL(httpUrl);
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(uri.openStream()));
        doc.normalizeDocument();
        NodeList xml = doc.getElementsByTagName("avatar");
        Log.v("xml_parser", "Avatar Content: " + xml.item(0).getTextContent());
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String generateNewXML(Document doc, String tag) {
    try {
        NodeList xml = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        serializer.transform(new DOMSource(xml.item(0)), new StreamResult(sw));
        String newXML = sw.toString();
        System.out.println("New XML: " + newXML);
        return newXML;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I have Get This Type Of `Error`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.XMLTokener.end
at org.json.XMLTokener.nextCDATA(XMLTokener.java:69)
at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:165)
at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:272)
at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:272)
at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:369)
at com.fragdeluxestats.model.DataHandler.getPlayerSummary(DataHandler.java:85)
at com.fragdeluxestats.model.DataAsyncTask.doInBackground(DataAsyncTask.java:45)
at com.fragdeluxestats.model.DataAsyncTask.doInBackground(DataAsyncTask.java:19)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The XML has two type `tags` as follows:

```
<avatar><![CDATA[http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/11/11c82457c292cc278ab84c6e912d9668491f7d3e_full.jpg]]></avatar>
```

Comment: Any news about this issue?

Comment: I decided to abandon the JSON due to the bug and process all the text in XML.